# Establishing a IBSS in 802.11

Tags: wifi

I know that for infrastructure BSS stations send management frames to AP to require connection(association etc.).

But how does IBSS set up connection in the first place?
What frames do they use to establish communication with each other?
Is there any explanation described in the 802.11 protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Your question itself is somewhat misguided.  Stations that are in an infrastructure BSS don't need to establish communication with each other.  All communication is done through the AP in the first place.